# How do I get a ContentPlaceHolder in ASP.NET to fill the page?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a Master page and many, many pages that use it.  On one or two of the pages, there is not enough content to fill the entire page.  This causes the footer to appear near the middle of the screen and the background to be visible at the bottom of the page.  I would like to know if it is possible to have the ContentPlaceHolder automatically generate white space to force the footer to the bottom of the page.  I have looked through the code of the master page and did not see anything that was forcing the size of the ContentPlaceHolder.  I also checked the two pages that I am having the issue with and did not see any explicit size declaration.  I have also Google'd the issue and did not see anything helpful.  Maybe I do not know the correct search terms...

I saw a similar question on here but it was for DIV tags.  I am not using DIV tags.

Thanks!

```
<body runat="server" id="main">
    <div id="wrap">
        <form id="template_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
            <table id="Table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="800" align="center" border="0"
                runat="server">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" width="800" colspan="2"><uc1:header id="Header" runat="server"></uc1:header></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="800" colspan="2" height="7"><asp:image id="imgShadow" runat="server" 
                                Height="100%" Width="100%" ImageUrl="~/Images/new_header_shadow.jpg" 
                                AlternateText="Shadow"></asp:image></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2" style="height: 24px"><uc1:betabadge id="BetaBadge1" runat="server"></uc1:betabadge></td></tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td width="0" height="100%"><uc1:sidebar id="Sidebar1" runat="server"></uc1:sidebar></td>
                        <td class="Content" width="790" height="330"><asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:contentplaceholder>
                            <!-- content goes here --></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <table cellpadding="5">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><uc1:feedback id="FeedBack1" runat="server" DESIGNTIMEDRAGDROP="259"></uc1:feedback></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><uc1:footer id="Footer2" runat="server"></uc1:footer></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: show your markup, please, or at least your master page

Comment: not 100% sure if I can upload any of the markup code

Comment: @Satanfx55: Add the relevant portion of the code only; remove anything proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this with "whitespace", you'll want to do this with CSS.

Look into docking your footer to the bottom of the page.

Here's an article: [MAKING YOUR FOOTER STAY PUT WITH CSS](http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/)

Answer (score 1):

ContentPlaceHolders do not output any HTML. You should place a div tag around the content placeholder, then use CSS to specify a min-height value. This will provide the whitespace you're looking for.

Comment: looking at my markup for the master page...I have a a div, and a form inside that, and a table inside that.  The content place holder is a td in that table.  I specified a min height for it and that seemed to resolve the issue.  Is there a way to have it dynamically determine the min height?

Comment: You'll want to use Javascript for this, since the amount of whitespace would depend on browser/resolution. Or, look at the link that hunter posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with CSS instead.

Take a look at [this website](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/). It contains everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from being probably really hard to do generically, if not impossible, filling up content for a ContentPlaceHolder with blank lines also isn't really user-friendly - since how much free space really should be displayed probably also depends on user's screen size!

I would recommend using the CSS [min-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) property on the container around your placeholder.